# Which HTTP METHOD need to use , if that rest controller method take list as input and give Map as response?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

We need to create one rest service , which need to return a Map and get List as input . So may i know which HTTP method more opt for this restservice method i need to configure , is it ok to use HttpMethod.POST for this method ? but post means to create any resource ,am i correct , but here the rest controller method , receives some list and return the Map as response .

So can any one please suggest which HttpMethod is good to use here please .

Note : yes i used to POST method , and rest service worked , but i am thinking that since i am returning Map in the return response , i thought that it is not goos to use .please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: What does it do other than returning a Map? What does the list contain? What is its size? If I send the same request twice (because I couldn't get th response, for example), would it produce a similar result, and would it have undesired side effects?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your endpoint gets some data, performs an action and returns result. Let's say you have a products endpoint `/products` and you want to for example get a map of prices for different set of customers for a product.

I've usually approached this problem by creating a new endpoint for an action. In our case it would be `/products/{productId}/generate-prices-map`.

Then you can use POST method, because you are not getting a object from the endpoint but *you are creating an action object*.

Anyway it's possible to use GET method with a list but I think it suck.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response , actually my case is like below

1 . Client sends , list of keys , then i need to send Map of above keys and related values . so may i know in this how the API end point should look like and what is the HTTP method i need to use  ?

Comment: I would do this: POST /some-entity/filter